# javascript onBlur to to avoid duplicate string

Tags: javascript

In my project I need onBlur event to check string have contain any duplicate character to remove it i.e text value has `01,02,04,01,07,2`  in the String after the comma 01 has to  duplicate value so I need `01,02,04,07,2`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you could do that

```js
var numberString = '01,02,04,01,07,2';
var result = [];

$.each(numberString.split(','), function(index, number) {
    if($.inArray(number, result) === -1) {
      result.push(number);
    }
});

document.write(result.join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:text").on('blur', function() {
    var textVal = $(this).val();
    var valArray = textVal.split(',');
    var newValArray = [];
    for(var i in valArray) {
        if(newValArray.indexOf(i) === -1) {
            newValArray.push(i);
        }
    }
    var newTextVal = newValArray.join();
    $(this).val(newTextVal);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split(",") method to create an array of the values and then loop through the array values and then use splice(0,1) method to remove the duplicate. After that you can revert the array back to a string using the join(",") method to create the string with the comma delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this reduce codes. It does what you need.

```
//I altered your number string to this.
var numberString = '01,02,04,01,07,2,07,10,55,55,10,02,500,450';

var strDedoop = function ( str ) {

    var strArr = [], // temp array
        numStrSplit = str.split(','); // split the number string by comma 

    //loop through the array 
    numStrSplit.forEach(function(currentValue) {
            // Ternary operation. If the number is not in the array it is put in.
            strArr.indexOf(currentValue) === -1 ? strArr.push(currentValue) : false;
    });

    return strArr.toString(); // return the array as a string.
}

strDedoop(numberString);
// returns "01,02,04,07,2,10,55,500,450"
```

You can use it this way.

```
$("input:text").on('blur', strDedoop(numberString));
```